# Populating empty space in adjacent table-cell displayed div to minimise blank space

Tags: html, css, tablecell

Suppose I have a basic div layout as below, where div A and div B are displayed as table-cell within a containing div set to display:table.

This works great for matching the height of both divs A and B to the height of the content of the tallest div, but in a lot of pages using this structure as a template on this particular site, the primarily text content of div B can be huge on some pages, and much shorter on others.

Is there a way that I can calculate the height of the blank space underneath div A, and use this to dynamically add x number of div C (which could be database driven dynamic content in a fixed height div) to leave as little blank space under the original div A as possible?

[image: diagram of divs]

Comment: Something like `wrapper.clientHeight - divA.offsetHeight`?

Comment: You haven't mentioned it but you'd have to use javascript to calculate them e.g. `var heightA = document.getElementById('elementA').offsetHeight;` etc

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a `<table>` rather than `<div>`.

`rowspan="2"` would cover 2 spaces left to right (span across columns in a row) and `colspan="2"` would cover 2 spaces up to down (span across rows in a column).  This needs to be used in your `<td>` tag... `<td colspan="2">Content</td>`